# jQuery / Javascript String replace

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, string

I would like to as some help.

Is there a certain method in javascript/jquery that would act like
the str_replace in php?

i mean, example if i have a string like this : `"l.123.aa-b"`

i would replace all `.` and `-` into `#`.

in php you would do something like this:

```
$a = l.123.aa-b;
$new_str = str_replace(array('-','.'),'#',$a);
```

any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: This has been reposted MANY times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just call `'string'.replace()`

```
var str = 'l.123.aa-b';
var newStr = str.replace('.', '#').replace('-', '#');

// or with a regex
var newStr = str.replace(/[\.-]/g, '#'); // Thanks for the correction, Andbdrew
```

Comment: @AlexWayne When I ran your solution in chrome devtools, it seemed like your regex solution targets the string ".-" instead of the character class containing "." and "-". Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: @AlexWayne your regex solution is now perfect! I believe the other one  still has an issue, at least in chrome. It seems like it only replaces the first "." in your example.

Comment: Yes you do have to use a regex with the `/g` flag to replace multiple occurrences.  Also good to point out :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this might work for you:

```
var str = 'l.123.aa-b';
var newStr = str.replace(/[\.-]+/g, '#');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a replace method in javascript which is similar to str_replace in php.
More info on w3schools - http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp